# Pair Sennheiser PXC 550 via Bluetooth (windows 7 x64) to HP Elitebook 840 g1

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, bluetooth, hp-elitebook

### My goal

Is to connect Sennheiser PXC 550 headset to the HP EliteBook 840 g1 (Intel Bluetooth chipset) having windows 7 x64.

### My approach

- Removed the old Intel Bluetooth drivers.
- I have downloaded latest drivers from the HP website - *sp84412.exe*.
- I have checked if it contains bluetooth drivers in path
  `C:\SWSetup\SP84412\Win7\vs64` (in the `Setup.xml`).

Apparently they do:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <Products xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2">
- <OS name="WIN7">
- <ProductName name="Bluetooth" desc="Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R) 4.0 Software">
  <NativeMSI /> 
  <AddlocalMSI /> 
  <CustomMSI /> 
  <AcceptUserCommands>True</AcceptUserCommands> 
  <RunPostExe>TRUE</RunPostExe> 
  </ProductName>
  </OS>
  <MSI>Intel Bluetooth.msi</MSI> 
- <OS name="WIN8">
- <ProductName name="Bluetooth" desc="Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R) 4.0 Software">
  <NativeMSI /> 
  <AddlocalMSI /> 
  <CustomMSI /> 
  <AcceptUserCommands>True</AcceptUserCommands> 
  <RunPostExe>TRUE</RunPostExe> 
  </ProductName>
  </OS>
  <MSI>Intel Bluetooth.msi</MSI> 
  </Products>
```

After the install successfully finishes (the short log):

```
[2018-5-7 12:46:14]Multi Package Installer Begins

[2018-5-7 12:46:14]OS/Bitness: Win7 64-bit

[2018-5-7 12:46:15]Hardware detected: Win7

[2018-5-7 12:46:15]IsDeviceInstallInProgress Entry

[2018-5-7 12:46:15]IsDeviceInstallInProgress:There is NO pending Device Installation Activities

[2018-5-7 12:46:15]Command: cmd.exe /c mkdir C:\system.sav\logs

[2018-5-7 12:46:15]Return Value: 1

[2018-5-7 12:46:15]IsDeviceInstallInProgress Entry

[2018-5-7 12:46:15]IsDeviceInstallInProgress:There is NO pending Device Installation Activities

[2018-5-7 12:50:30]Command: cmd.exe /c attrib +h C:\system.sav /s /d

[2018-5-7 12:50:30]Return Value: 0

[2018-5-7 12:50:30]IsDeviceInstallInProgress Entry

[2018-5-7 12:50:30]IsDeviceInstallInProgress:There is NO pending Device Installation Activities

[2018-5-7 12:52:37]Command: Win7\vs64\Setup.exe /qn /l*v C:\system.sav\logs\INTELBLUEWP.log SSDISABLE=TRUE REBOOT=ReallySuppress

[2018-5-7 12:52:37]Return Value: 0

[2018-5-7 12:52:37]Multi Package Installer Ends
```

The complete log from the installation is [here - INTELBLUEWP.log](https://pastebin.com/ympiATMy)

I also tried to download drivers directly from Intel (`BT_20.30.0_64_Win7.exe`) but the drivers were exactly the same as from HP.

I'm still missing a driver for Bluetooth Peripheral Device:

> BTHENUM{deab91e4-670f-11e1-9ace-30bc4824019b}_VID&00010075_PID&0100
>   BTHENUM{deab91e4-670f-11e1-9ace-30bc4824019b}_LOCALMFG&0002

I don't seem to find the correct driver for this device.  Probably that is the reason why my headset does not connect correctly.

How to find out the correct driver?  Thank you for any hint(s).

**Edit - partial success**

I have managed to pair the the Headphones/set.  You have go into the "manual pairing" mode.  Hold the Mode Control button for 4 seconds (on the headset), until you hear the voice saying "pairing" and then you install your Headset.  I can now use it for telco or playback which was the main reason for doing this exercise.

However, I have ended with two more **unknown Bluetooth Peripheral Devices**:

```
BTHENUM\{0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010082_PID&0046
BTHENUM\{0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_LOCALMFG&0002

BTHENUM\{63331358-23c1-11e5-b696-feff819cdc9f}_VID&00010082_PID&0046
BTHENUM\{63331358-23c1-11e5-b696-feff819cdc9f}_LOCALMFG&0002
```

I wish Microsoft would just improve ways of detecting unknown hardware.

**Edit** Apparently Sennheiser does not ship any drivers I know of.

the [Sennheiser updater](https://en-us.sennheiser.com/headset-software-pc) software supports only these following devices:

```
  <Model>Sennheiser D 10</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser D 10 for Lync</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser D 10 for upgrading</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SP 10</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SP 10 for Lync</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SP 20</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SP 20 D UC</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SP 20 D MS</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SP 20 for Lync</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser BTD 500 USB</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser BTD 800 USB</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser BTD 800 USB for Lync</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser MB Pro 1</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser MB Pro 2</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser Presence</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser CEHS-CI 02</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser DECT</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser DECT for Lync</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser DECT for upgrading</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SD</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SD for Lync</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SD for upgrading</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC30 Control</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC30 for Lync</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC60 Control</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC60 for Lync</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC40 USB CTRL</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC40 USB for MS</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC70 USB CTRL</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC70 USB for MS</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC230</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC230 Control</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC230 for Lync</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC230 USB CTRL II</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC230 USB for MS II</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC260</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC260 Control</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC260 for Lync</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC260 USB CTRL II</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC260 USB for MS II</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC630 Control</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC630 for Lync</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC660 Control</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC660 for Lync</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser USB-ED 01</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser USB-RJ9 01</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser USB-ED CC 01 for MS</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser USB-ED CC 01</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser UUSB8 UC Controller</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser MB 660</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser MB 660 MS</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SCx5 USB CTRL</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SCx5 USB MS</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SCx5 USB MS EUL</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser SC6x5 USB</Model> 
  <Model>GSX 1000 Main Audio</Model> 
  <Model>GSX 1200 Pro Main Audio</Model> 
  <Model>Sennheiser Main Audio</Model>
```

When I tried to update it I got the following message:

[image: Not supported]

In simple mode it at least detects the headset:
[image: Headset detected]

Comment: There sould be a button or an FN-Key combination to enable/disable wireless, which will also change the bluetooth settings.

Comment: @davidbaumann I'm having issue pairing the headset with computer.  I know how to turn on Bluetooth.

Comment: Sennheiser doesn't produce a driver?

Comment: @TrippKinetics not that I could find https://en-us.sennheiser.com/wireless-headphone-headset-bluetooth-noise-cancelling-pxc-550-travel (downloads section).  I will try to dissect their software, from here https://en-us.sennheiser.com/headset-software-pc, to see if there are any hidden drivers.

Answer (score -1):

I had same trouble connecting to a Dell laptop.  Finally I discovered that the PCX 550 has to be set to Phone Mode.  Then it recognises the PC!

Comment: This is more like comment or than answer. The problem is not pcx 550 recognition.  The computer sees the the pxc 550 (as you can see from the screenshots).  The problem are the drivers.

Answer (score -1):

Colin is right,

I had mine connected to an Avantree device for the TV and the connection to Dell laptop  was not right. No Headphone & mic icon just a gerneral Bluetooth device.

After turning off the Avantree & removing the PXC550 from the Dell.

The PXC500 was connected to my Pixel3 and then it discovered properly as a headphone set on my XPS15.

Allen

Comment: Hi Allen,  this is again more of a comment because it does not solve the issue with drivers.